# write html using StAX API

Tags: java, html, xml

I am new to Java, I am using StAX api to write html, (I know it is for xml)  but in the method writer.writeCharacters() if I added the unicode string
& #x25ca;, the html content contains & amp;#x25ca; (Space is not there between & and amp).
How to add special characters which html supports. I mean I no escaping should happen.

Using just a FileWriter is enough to write large html files or is there any specific API's are there. I searched the web, I found many solutions but if lot of String content is involved how efficiently can I write using FileWriter without consuming more memory.

```
 public class BuildHtml
   {
    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BuildHtml.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
       {        
    final String inFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test_output/output.html";
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    XMLStreamWriter writer = null;
    try 
    {
        fout = new FileOutputStream(inFilePath);
        writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(fout);
        writer.writeStartElement("html");
        writer.writeStartElement("head");
        writer.writeStartElement("body");
        writer.writeStartElement("table");
        writer.writeAttribute("align", "center");
        writer.writeAttribute("border", "1");
        writer.writeStartElement("tbody");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) 
        {
            writer.writeStartElement("tr");
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) 
            {
                writer.writeStartElement("td");
                writer.writeCharacters(("" + j));
                writer.writeCharacters("&#x25ca;")
                writer.writeEndElement();
            }
            writer.writeEndElement();
        }
        writer.writeEndDocument();
        System.out.println("XML created.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("exception", e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(writer != null)
            {
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            if(fout != null)
            {
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException | XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
}
```

Comment: HTML is not XML! Also, you should consider using a [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system).

Comment: yes, I will manage it, but is there any api's which are memory efficient and with user friendly interface or do I have to use StAX.

Comment: @DonRoby not sure where you get that, but thats 100% wrong. one major difference is that end tags are (by specification!) not required for all tags. html parsers can handle that just fine, an xml parser would throw an error. see https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/HTML_vs._XHTML btw: xhtml5 is practically dead and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149839/is-xhtml5-dead-or-is-it-just-an-synonym-of-html5

Comment: I'll retract my comment.  Apparently W3C took a wrong turn.  (opinion of course!)

Answer (score 3):

As already suggested in the comments, use a [template engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template_system).

Advantages are: smaller code size, easier to write, no overhead of building an in-memory representation like DOM, since template engine usually stream their generated output.

Here is your example written in [CSP](http://www.civilian-framework.org/doc-templates-csp.html):

```
template(int rows, int cols)
{{
     <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
         <table align="center" border="1">
         <tbody>
         @for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
            <tr> 
            @for (int j=0; j<cols; j++)  
                 <td><%j%></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
     </body>
     </html>
 }}
```

Comment: Much more readable than the code OP posted; plus anyone who knows html could easily change the format or add styling, without having to be an expert in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Getting HTML using StAX is not likely to be straightforward, and the best and easy result one may achieve on this way is XHTML as an XML flavor.

And if you need plain HTML, then it is possible to obtain is without any templates, just using SAX and default XSLT transformer, the latter having intrinsic capability of HTML output:

```
String encoding = "UTF-8";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("myfile.html");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, encoding);
StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(writer);

SAXTransformerFactory saxFactory =
    (SAXTransformerFactory) TransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler tHandler = saxFactory.newTransformerHandler();
tHandler.setResult(streamResult);

Transformer transformer = tHandler.getTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, encoding);
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

writer.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
writer.flush();
tHandler.startDocument();
    tHandler.startElement("", "", "html", new AttributesImpl());
        tHandler.startElement("", "", "head", new AttributesImpl());
            tHandler.startElement("", "", "title", new AttributesImpl());
                tHandler.characters("Hello".toCharArray(), 0, 5);
            tHandler.endElement("", "", "title");
        tHandler.endElement("", "", "head");
        tHandler.startElement("", "", "body", new AttributesImpl());
            tHandler.startElement("", "", "p", new AttributesImpl());
                tHandler.characters("5 > 3".toCharArray(), 0, 5); // note '>' character
            tHandler.endElement("", "", "p");
        tHandler.endElement("", "", "body");
    tHandler.endElement("", "", "html");
tHandler.endDocument();
writer.close();
```

Note that XSLT transformer will release you from the burden of escaping special characters like `>`, as it takes necessary care of it by itself.

And it is easy to wrap SAX methods like `startElement()` and `characters()` to something more convenient to one's taste...

And it may be worth noting that dealing without templates gives you more freedom in terms of the resulting document size...